# Replace Value in XML with ParseText by using groovy script

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I want to update value in XML with parseText.

This is my XML

```
def xmlText  = '''<BookRoot>
    <Book>
        <startDate>2005-02-14T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        <endDate>2015-01-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
        <Author>Manu</Author>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <startDate>2005-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        <endDate>9999-12-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
        <Author>Liverpool</Author>
    </Book>
</BookRoot>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlText);
```

This is expected result.

```
<BookRoot>
    <Book>
        <startDate>CurrentDate</startDate>
        <endDate>FutureDate</endDate>
        <Author>Manu</Author>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <startDate>CurrentDate</startDate>
        <endDate>FutureDate</endDate>
        <Author>Liverpool</Author>
    </Book>
</BookRoot>
```

I tried to use this code

```
xml.Book.each{ it->
    it.startDate[0].value = 'CurrentDate'
    it.endDate[0].value = 'FutureDate'
  }

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

but startDate's value and endDate's value are not updated.

Comment: Put placeholder variables into your xmlText variable, like this https://gr8fanboy.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/groovy-script-showing-most-active-participants-on-the-grails-mailing-list/ (look for the dumpResultToDisk def statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `replaceBody` on the tags.  E.g.

```
    it.startDate.replaceBody 'CurrentDate'
```